# Is it appropriate to use IAM credentials to connect to AWS Aurora from Spring via JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, amazon-aurora

I'm writing Spring Java application and I've to connect to Aurora DB. Guys from data team want to use IAM roles to manage DB access.
I wonder if it's a good approach, because my app will have to refresh token each 15 minutes and use it as a password to connect to DB. Does it mean that new connection has to be created each time? Does anyone have such a setup in the application on production? Maybe it's better to use DB username and password?
Every opinion or comment is very important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new token every 15 minutes. You just need to use the token within 15 minutes after creating it, thats all. Once a connection is established, it does not matter if the token has expired. However, if your connection breaks, and you need to re-open new connections, then that would the time when you need to generate new tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the database connection pool and then refreshes the connection every 15 minutes, it is quite a heavy task as pool will be created on every refresh.

As far as Spring is concerned, you can go for the username and password to connect to the database as it is safe and one-time connection process.
I've used Amazon RDBMS with the latter said method and found it good and reliable.